# How to search for a value in a pandas matrix and give the column names?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Im new to programming with python and pandas and I have to write a script that, when given a matrix, finds the max values and prints the column names and row names the value is in. I have already searched here for an answer and there is a similar question, but the answer doesn't work for me:

```
matrix2 = pd.DataFrame(matrix1, index=row_names, columns=column_names)
print(matrix2)
print(matrix2.values.max())
print((matrix2 == (matrix2.values.max())).idxmax())
```

This is what I got so far, the output I get is:

```
            ABC123  DEF456  GHI789  JKL012  MNO057  QRS047
ABC123      40      16      -5       1      -4       1
DEF456      16      38      -5       1      -7       1
GHI789      -5      -5      58      -5      -1      -5
JKL012       1       1      -5      60       5      60
MNO057      -4      -7      -1       5      32       5
QRS047       1       1      -5      60       5      60
60
ABC123    ABC123
DEF456    ABC123
GHI789    ABC123
JKL012    JKL012
MNO057    ABC123
QRS047    JKL012
dtype: object
```

The desired output I would like to get in this case is:

```
JKL012 JKL012
JKL012 QRS047
QRS047 JKL012
QRS047 QRS047
```

I dont really understand why it gives me the output I have.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`DF.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) so that you get those row and column values corresponding to the maximum value as the index for the creation of the new dataframe as shown:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[df == df.values.max()].stack().index.values.tolist())
```

[image]